# Perl m operator question

Tags: perl

Why does this code print 51 and not 26? I'm trying to extract the "values".
That is I want(the bold one): <option value="**Andaman & Nicobar**">Andaman & Nicobar</option>

As per definition m with g operator in list context should return pattern in parantheses?

```
my $firstpage=<<'EOF';
 <option value="Andaman & Nicobar">Andaman & Nicobar</option>
            <option value="Andhra Pradesh">Andhra Pradesh</option>
            <option value="Assam">Assam</option>
            <option value="Bihar">Bihar</option>
            <option value="Calcutta Telecom District">Calcutta Telecom District</option>
            <option value="Chennai Telecom District">Chennai Telecom District</option>
            <option value="Chhattisgarh">Chhattisgarh</option>
            <option value="Gujarat">Gujarat</option>
            <option value="Haryana">Haryana</option>
            <option value="Himachal Pradesh">Himachal Pradesh</option>
            <option value="Jammu & Kashmir">Jammu & Kashmir</option>
            <option value="Jharkhand">Jharkhand</option>
            <option value="Karnataka">Karnataka</option>
            <option value="Kerala">Kerala</option>
            <option value="Madhya Pradesh">Madhya Pradesh</option>
            <option value="Maharashtra">Maharashtra</option>
            <option value="North East I">North East I</option>
            <option value="North East II">North East II</option>
            <option value="Orissa">Orissa</option>
            <option value="Punjab">Punjab</option>
            <option value="Rajasthan">Rajasthan</option>
            <option value="Tamilnadu">Tamilnadu</option>
            <option value="UP East">UP East</option>
            <option value="UP West">UP West</option>
            <option value="Uttaranchal">Uttaranchal</option>
            <option value="West Bengal">West Bengal</option>
EOF

my @cities=$firstpage=~m{(?<=")([^"]*)(?=")}gs;

print scalar @cities;
```

Comment: minor observation, that doesnt look like valid html, you should escape the & to &amp;

Comment: Had you printed `@cities` and not `scalar @cities`, you would have had your answer a little sooner. If *digest* information throws you, then don't print just digest information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each /g match starts where the previous one left off, but since you are using zero-width assertions, you aren't actually consuming the ".  So

```
">Andaman & Nicobar</option>
        <option value="
```

is considered a match too.

Do:

```
my @cities = $firstpage =~ m/"([^"]*)"/gs;
```

instead.  Note that if there are capturing parentheses, only the contents of those are returned by m//g on success in list context.

Answer (score 2):

a better one would be:

```
my @cities=($firstpage=~/value="([^"]+)"/gs);
```

in this case

Answer (score 1):

The regex is grabbing what you think are the quoted cities, as well as, the text between end-quote of one city and the beginning quote of the next city. I assume if you don't make the zero-width assertion on the end double quote, your problem will go away.