# What is this field separator (^M)?

Tags: perl, separator

I run into this one while trying to parse a text file with Perl. The original file looks like this in vim:
[image]

When I tried to print the 2nd column (87 here), somehow, the ^M showed up in vim:
[image]

I'm just curious what this "^M" is? Does anyone know? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl m operator question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490321/perl-m-operator-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^M` is ASCII character 13, known as a carriage return.  MS-DOS uses a carriage return followed by a line feed (ASCII 10) to mark the end of a line.  Unix systems use a line feed only.  Usually you will "see" a carriage return when using an editor that thinks your file is using Unix style line endings but actually has MS-DOS style line endings.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense as I got this file from a friend using windows OS... darn, I was so confused..

Comment: If you like the answer feel free to mark it as accepted.  There are several helpful answers on stackoverflow for dealing with line ending issues.  Also look for the dos2unix and unix2dos utilities on your system.

Comment: That could be another answer, but "^m" means "/m Let ^ and $ match next to embedded \n." according to the O'Riley book.